# How to run DesktopDuplication Sample Code on windows10

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8.1, msdn, windows-10-desktop

Hi I am trying some application involving using [Desktop Duplication Sample Code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a). However on the page it is mentioned it can ONLY be used with Windows 8.1 
However is there any way possible to use it with Windows 10 as well?

Any inputs on how to go about trying to implement this for windows 10 will be appreciated.

Comment: The page is from 2013, when Windows 8.1 was the latest version. They might mean "Windows 8.1 or later".

Comment: But I tried running the sample code on a windows 10 laptop. It returns a black screen